# How to generate UINT8 TFlite model with UINT8 input & output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, quantization, tensorflow-lite

*see possible solution at the end of the post*

---

I am trying to fully quantize the keras-vggface model from [rcmalli](https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface) to run on an NPU. The model is a Keras model (not tf.keras).

When using TF 1.15 for quantization with:

```
print(tf.version.VERSION)
num_calibration_steps=5

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file('path_to_model.h5')        

#converter.post_training_quantize = True  # This only makes the weight in8 but does not initialize model quantization  
def representative_dataset_gen():
    for _ in range(num_calibration_steps):
        pfad='path_to_image(s)'
        img=cv2.imread(pfad)
        # Get sample input data as a numpy array in a method of your choosing.
        yield [img]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_gen
tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
open("quantized_model", "wb").write(tflite_quant_model)
```

The model is converted but as I need full int8 quantization, I add:

```
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8  # or tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8  # or tf.uint8
```

This error message appears:

> ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Got value of type UINT8 but expected type FLOAT32 for input 0, name: input_1

clearly, the input of the model still requires float32.

**Questions**:

1. Do I have to adapt the quantization method that the input dtype is changed ? or
2. Do I have to change the input layer of the model to dtype int8 beforehand?
3. Or is that actually reporting that the model is not actually quantized?

If 1 or 2 is the answer, would you also have a best practice tip for me?

---

**Addition**:

Using :

```
h5_path = 'my_model.h5'
model = keras.models.load_model(h5_path)
model.save(os.getcwd() +'/modelTF2')
```

to save the h5 as pb with TF 2.2 and then using `converter=tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)`

as TF 2.x tflite takes floats, and convert them to uint8s [internally](https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/issues/13#issuecomment-543758317) . I thought that could be a solution. Unfortunately, this error message appears:

> tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model giving 'str' object has no attribute 'call'

Apparently TF2.x cannot handle pure keras models.

using `tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file()` to solve this error just repeats the error from above, as we are back again at "TF 1.15" level.

---

**Addition 2**

Another solution is to transfer the keras model to tf.keras manually. I will look into that if there is no other solution.

---

**Regarding the comment of Meghna Natraj**

To recreate the model **(using TF 1.13.x)** just:

`pip install git+https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface.git`

and

```
from keras_vggface.vggface import VGGFace   
pretrained_model = VGGFace(model='resnet50', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3), pooling='avg')  # pooling: None, avg or max
pretrained_model.summary()
pretrained_model.save("my_model.h5") #using h5 extension
```

The input layer is connected. Too bad, that looked like a good/easy fix.
[image: summary of the first few layers of the VGGface model]

---

**Possible Solution**

It seems to work using TF 1.15.3 I used 1.15.0 beforehand. I will check if I did something else different by accident.

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason why this fails is that the model has input tensors that are not connected to the output tensor, i.,e they are probably unused.

Here is a [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jQjTugOARwlo60UC-UfnKhH8HPXZi1D4?usp=sharing) where I've reproduced this error. Modify the `io_type` at the beginning of the notebook to `tf.uint8` to see an error similar to one you got.

**SOLUTION**

You need to manually inspect the model and to see if there are any inputs that are dangling/lost/not connected to the output and remove them.

Post a link to the model and I can try to debug it as well.

Comment: hi Meghna Natraj, thank you for your idea. I checked the whole model. It does not seem that there are loose ends. Please see my addition regarding your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```py
def representative_data_gen():
  for input_value in tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_images).batch(1).take(100):
    # Model has only one input so each data point has one element.
    yield [input_value]

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen

tflite_model_quant = converter.convert()
```

generates a Float32 model with Float32 inputs and outputs. This:

```py
def representative_data_gen():
  for input_value in tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_images).batch(1).take(100):
    yield [input_value]

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen
# Ensure that if any ops can't be quantized, the converter throws an error
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
# Set the input and output tensors to uint8 (APIs added in r2.3)
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8

tflite_model_quant = converter.convert()
```

generates a UINT8 model with UINT8 inputs and outputs

You can make sure this is the case by:

```py
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_model_quant)
input_type = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['dtype']
print('input: ', input_type)
output_type = interpreter.get_output_details()[0]['dtype']
print('output: ', output_type)
```

which returns:

```bash
input:  <class 'numpy.uint8'>
output:  <class 'numpy.uint8'>
```

if you went for a full UINT8 quantization. You can double check this by inspecting your model visually using `netron`